# how to install older version of gcc -3 or gcc-4 in ubuntu 20

Tags: gcc, makefile, ubuntu-20.04, gcc4.7

I'm trying to install an older version of gcc-4 on my Ubuntu system

- Make a build directory (`mkdir gcc-build && cd gcc-build`)
- Download the source file: `wget http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.0/gcc-4.8.0.tar.bz2` (adjust this command to use an appropriate mirror site.
- Unzip the file (`tar -xvjf <file name>`)
- Install some additional libraries (`sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev libc6-dev`)
- Compile the source: `./gcc-4.8.0/configure --prefix=/app/gcc/4.8.0`
- Run make (This will take some time to complete. Go make some coffee, or bake some cookies. ;-))
- Install the code: `sudo make install`

CPU architecture

```
lscpu
Architecture:                    aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          16
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       4
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       ARM
Model:                           3
Model name:                      Cortex-A72
Stepping:                        r0p3
BogoMIPS:                        166.66
L1d cache:                       512 KiB
L1i cache:                       768 KiB
L2 cache:                        8 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-15
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Not affected
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Branch predictor hardening
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid
```

and finally run the **sudo make install**
got this error

```
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/gcc-build'
/bin/bash ./gcc-4.8.0/mkinstalldirs /app/gcc/4.8.0 /app/gcc/4.8.0
/bin/bash: line 3: cd: ./fixincludes: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3405: install-fixincludes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/gcc-build'
make: *** [Makefile:2196: install] Error 2
```

how can I fix this issue

Comment: Try running `./configure && make` in the top-level gcc source directory.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. but issue still remain

configure: error: C++ compiler missing or inoperational
make[2]: *** [Makefile:7573: configure-stage1-libcpp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/downlods/gcc-4.8.1'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:18649: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/downlods/gcc-4.8.1'
make: *** [Makefile:883: all] Error 2

Comment: This is a different issue. Do you have some other version of gcc installed?

Comment: I'm installed gcc-9 for the compilation, I need to install multiple GCC on a single machine . I have to compile the goldfish kernel. it only support the gcc-3 to 4. @n. 'pronouns' m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you have updated package manager, in doubt you can run following commands (in the same order given, which should run without errors):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you need to ensure `build-essential` installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After that you can install required version of gcc (example: gcc-4):

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4
```

Now the part of selecting specific version of gcc by following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4 4
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

By this way you can switch between multiple versions of gcc too. The second command in the last step will give you a menu like option to select among available(installed) gcc versions to be set.

Comment: Trying to install directly using `apt-get` gives me `Unable to locate package gcc-4`.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, for example, ubuntu 22.04 has only gcc 9, 10, 11, 12, and 13 available so it is not possible to install gcc-8 or below.

Comment: I have written a general approach, ie., when your Ubuntu is supporting the gcc version of your choice. If you need an older version of gcc which is no more supported, then please add the mirrors where your gcc version's .deb are still distributed.
Check this answer for more info on adding older distro to your newer Ubuntu OS: https://askubuntu.com/a/1450862/245258