# how to install older version of gcc on debian

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, debian

I know there are bunch of references on stackoverflow or other resources, but I couldn't find any applicable solution.

Followings are some of the solution I tried.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5
sudo apt install gcc-4.5
```

gives error E: `Package 'gcc-4.5' has no installation candidate`

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

gives error
`E: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.`

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

gives error `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.`

I'm really stuck on this simple problem for a few days. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do not do it. It is too complex and you risk to broke your environment. Just install a docker image or a virtual machine and install a old version of Debian or Ubuntu. it is much quicker (and safer, because you do not break dependencies)

Comment: You can have multiple versions of gcc installed. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593100/how-to-install-older-version-of-gcc-3-or-gcc-4-in-ubuntu-20